# Validate New CIM Payment Profile

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have just begun testing my app in `liveMode` using the C# CIM SDK.

I was under the impression that adding a new credit card with an incorrect expiration or cvv would throw an error in `liveMode` because it is invalid.

However I am able to create new credit cards with invalid combinations of card number, expiration, and/or cvv.

I can even successfully create `Authorize` only transactions. I do not receive an error until I try to create an `AuthoirizeAndCapture` transaction, because it gets declined.

I don't want to have to create a new payment profile, perform an `AuthorizeAndCapture` on it, and delete the payment profile if it is declined or void the transaction if it goes through everytime a new payment profile is created.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to validate a new CIM Payment Profile?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @kamalpreet I ended up doing a $1 authorization when creating a new card, if it's approved I immediately void the $1 authorization, and continue on, if it fails I delete the payment profile immediately and throw an exception. Not ideal but it's been running fine in production since about the time this question was asked.

Comment: Ohh!! But isn't it a good idea to just try to authorize a credit card without creating a profile first..if successfull void it and then create the profile?? Anyway, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`liveMode` sends a $0.00 (or $0.01 if the processor does not yet support $0.00 transactions) along with the credit card information to the processor who runs it as a normal transaction. What's important to know is that invalid expiration dates or CVV numbers will *not* necessarily result in a credit card being declined. Some credit card issuers will approve transactions with invalid expiration dates and invalid CVV numbers will not result in a decline either. If it is incorrect you will simply be notified of the result and then you have to decide if you want to accept the transaction or not. I'm not sure if that is possible with CIM so invalid CVV numbers are non-factors here.

If you really want to validate a credit card before creating a CIM profile you can use the AIM API with a $0.00 transaction and then check the CVV result code response.